# Pygame.mixer.Sound .set_volume returns error in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I try to create some short signal with pygame in Raspberry Pi B2
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
import time
from array import array
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 1024)
pygame.init()

class ToneSound(pygame.mixer.Sound):
    def __init__(self, frequency, volume):
        self.frequency = frequency
        pygame.mixer.Sound.__init__(self, self.build_samples())
        self.set_volume(volume)

    def build_samples(self):
        period = int(round(pygame.mixer.get_init()[0] / self.frequency))
        samples = array("h", [0] * period)
        amplitude = 2 ** (abs(pygame.mixer.get_init()[1]) - 1) - 1
        for time in xrange(period):
            if time < period / 2:
                samples[time] = amplitude
            else:
                samples[time] = -amplitude
        return samples

tone_obj = ToneSound(frequency = 800, volume = .5)

tone_obj.play(-1) #the -1 means to loop the sound
time.sleep(2)
tone_obj.stop()
```

When I run it, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "beep.py", line 29, in <module>
        tone_obj = ToneSound(frequency = 800, volume = .5)
    File "beep.py", line 15, in __init__
        self.set_volume(volume)
TypeError: fromfile() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

When I commented the set_volume function, the next error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "beep.py", line 29, in <module>
        tone_obj.play(-1) #the -1 means to loop the sound
TypeError: fromfile() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What can be the problem?
I updated the pygame, updated all needed libraries - the same result.
According to pygame documentation, set_volume takes one argument only.
I really don't know what to do...

Comment: does it work without `set_volume` ? maybe problem is something different.  `fromfile` suggests `Sound` try to read data from file - maybe it treats your sample as file object or something.

Comment: @furas - Thank you for your comment. I edited the question. I get the same problem...

Comment: I can only say - it works on Linux Mint. I don't know where is my RPi to check it on RPi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar problem posted to the Raspberry Pi site,
see ["Morse-code Project not working..."](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=122552&p=825941).

The solution there was:

1. Change:  `pygame.mixer.Sound.init(self, self.build_samples())`
2. To:      `pygame.mixer.Sound.init(self, buffer=self.build_samples())`

Adding `buffer=` worked for me.